# NetBean 6.9 GUI Designer Source File

Tags: user-interface, netbeans

I changed a JLabel's text to be "Your Name:" through the Property window. I want to know where this "Your Name: " is stored?

Also in the Property window, I changed this JLabel's name to be "lblName" but in the FrameView.java file it is still JLabel1. So weired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Where is the label's text stored...

   The text is probably in the file
   Bundle.properties (unless you have
   disabled automatic
   internationalization)
2. Why didn't the variable name change
   when I changed the Name property...

   The Name property is a property on
   ALL java.awt.Component objects and a
   JLabel is one of those things.  If
   you do want to change the variable
   name in the code, right-click on the
   component and select the 'Change
   Variable Name...' item.

Comment: The texts are in XXView.properties. Thank you!